# How find world between another words in grep?

Tags: grep

I have xml-file and  I need to find some text between  
I do

```
grep -oE  "(<title>)(.+)(</title>)" glTextureView.xml
```

and output is

```
<titel> assa </titel>
```

That is logical. How can I output only assa? Aslo I write:

```
grep -oE  "(<title>)(.+)(</title>)" glTextureView.xml | grep -v "</?title>"
```

But my output is empty,because it deletes all string.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you need to know that using regex to parse xml is risky.

If you want a dirty&quick solution, try this:

```
grep -oP "(?<=<title>)[^<]*" foo.xml
```

Comment: Thank you! This is work, but I new in grep. Can you explain what does it means "?<=" ?

Comment: @user3288344 it is look behind. matching text following `<title>`. google regex look behind to find more examples.